# PHP Memcached Requesting Empty Key throws 500 Server error

Tags: php, memcached, cgi

My site is hosted on webfaction and is running php5.4

I am trying to get memcached up and running but am running into a very weird error

Any help is very appreciated, the hosting company is working hard with me to try to get this solved but ... please see below

The following code works

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$mc = new Memcached();
$mc->addServer('localhost', 32323);
echo "Setting foo to Hello! <Br />";
$mc->set("foo", "Hello!");
echo "Setting bar to Memcached.. <Br />";
$mc->set("bar", "Memcached...");

echo "dumping values <br />";
$arr = array(
$mc->get("foo"),
$mc->get("bar")
);
var_dump($arr);
```

But the following does not

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$mc = new Memcached();
$mc->addServer('localhost', 32323);

$mc->get("cat");
```

It actually throws this error

```
500 – Internal Server Error
The page you requested is currently unavailable. Please try again later.

If you are the website owner, please see Error: 500 Internal Server Error documentation for more information and possible steps to resolve the problem.
```

Here are some thing to keep in mind that I have tried

- Yes, it is memcacheD not memcache
- I have created isolated environment to test this but in all cases if
  I request the value before setting it, I can't even try/catch any
  errors (doesn't propagate that high). Almost as if it doesn't reach the PHP-level

From my PHP error log I get

```
[Sat Feb 02 19:55:33 2013] [error] [client 209.29.54.55] Premature end of script headers: php54.cgi
```

Comment: "Premature end of script headers" error is know to be cause by a broad number of reasons and would probably require you to test each possible cause (plus some guesswork) to diagnose.

Try to narrow down possible causes as help is scarce for these sort of problems. Have a look at:

https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/297136-Premature-end-of-script-headers?s=1848d91d520adeb946e3bf782a3e2b8d&p=1682659&viewfull=1#post1682659

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer I got from the webhosting in case others run into the same problem

Okay, we've finally determined exactly what the problem is:

> php53 -c . index.php  Before 
> php53: symbol lookup error:
>   ~/php53-exts/memcached.so: undefined symbol:
>   memcached_last_error_errno
>
> Specifically, what's happening is that you built memcached against
>   libmemcached 1.0.15, but our server already has an older version of
>   libmemcached installed, version 0.31.
>
> The newer version of libmemcached is necessary; memcached 2.1.0 will
>   not build against the older libmemcached. But when your PHP actually
>   *runs*, it's trying to link against the shared libmemcached instead of the one you installed into ~/lib
>
> Okay, it is possible to rebuild the PHP memcached PECL module
>   statically against libmemcached, but then it also requires building
>   memcached itself against the same libmemcached as well. Then, you have
>   to ensure that your PHP calls the appropriate ~/bin/memcached when you
>   do "new Memcached()" in the PHP code.
>
> This is a bit too much work, so I'm looking into having the versions
>   of memcached and libmemcached upgraded on all of our servers. A newer
>   memcached + libmemcached would allow a new version of the memcached
>   PHP PECL module to be installed without needing a local installation
>   of libmemcached and static-linking for the binary.